# Apple Watch can't change font in label

Tags: fonts, label, nsattributedstring, watchkit, apple-watch

I can't change font in label.
I added "Font provided by application" in Info.plist in WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension and added font in Bundle Recourse both project.
When I compiled code with 
`for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
NSLog(@"|%@"",family);`
The list of all the fonts I find that is connected: "|Courier New|"
But it not work:

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString: @"Yano rocks! Always"];

    [attString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier New" size:20.0]} range:NSMakeRange(0, attString.string.length)];

    [self.loadingLabel setAttributedText:attString];
```

or

```
UIFont* labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier New" size:16];
NSAttributedString* lab = [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
initWithString:@"Text" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: labelFont}];
[self.label setAttributedText:lab];
```

Also, any system font does not work!

Pls, help!

p.s. I did everything according to instructions: [link] (http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/53710/how-do-i-use-custom-fonts-in-my-apple-watch-app/)

I use Watch App(not Notification and Glance).

Comment: This code set text for lable, but not attributes(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood what was the problem. Xcode does not establish a standard fonts such as Arial, Courier and etc., but installs fonts that are not in the system and downloaded from the Internet. 
So when I put Arial and Courier and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I set the font on my WKInterfaceLabel with code that looks like yours. Here are a few things to check to see if you can figure out what is wrong.

1. Check and make sure you actually wired up self.label to the correct label in your storyboard.  Run the debugger and make sure self.label is not nil.
2. Run the debugger and make sure labelFont is not nil.  If it is nil, try it with a system font and new go back to "Courier New".

Here is the code I am using to set the font.  This actually sets two different fonts in the label to have the units at a smaller size.

```
-(void)setValue:(NSString*)value withUnits:(NSString*)units onLabel:(WKInterfaceLabel*)lable useLargeSize:(BOOL)useLargeSize
{
    NSMutableAttributedString* str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[value stringByAppendingString:units]];

    if (useLargeSize)
    {
        [str setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:36]} range:NSMakeRange(0, value.length)];
        [str setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]} range:NSMakeRange(value.length, units.length)];
    }
    else
    {
        [str setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]} range:NSMakeRange(0, value.length)];
        [str setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]} range:NSMakeRange(value.length, units.length)];
    }
    [lable setAttributedText:str];

}
```

Comment: I checked again, it's not nil. Label displays a message in the specified text, but without the custom(or system) font.

Comment: Now that is interesting.  Your code is almost identical to mine and mine is working.  If your font and label are not nil then I am not sure.

Comment: Maybe I need to put some other settings?
Can you show how to use system fonts programmatically?

Comment: What is xcode you use? When I use xcode 6.2 beta all worked fine. But I updated xcode to 6.2 release and now I have this problem.

Comment: I added my code to my answer.  I am using the latest Xcode 6.2 release from the App Store.

Comment: This code is well set different font sizes, but when i try set different font it's not working(when change systemFontOfSize to fontWithName)

Comment: Check your custom font and make sure it's target is set to your watch app.